# Pylab - Change historgram colors based on RGB axis

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a python dictionary I'm using to get a histogram:

```
colors = {(97, 103, 105): 638059, (129, 140, 143): 562526, (55, 58, 62): 431610, (189, 193, 193): 460605}

import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
dict_index = np.arange(len(colors))
pl.bar(dict_index, colors.values(), align='center', width=0.5)
pl.xticks(dict_index, colors.keys())
ymax = max(colors.values()) + 1
pl.ylim(0, ymax)
pl.show()
```

The keys represent RGB color codes and my values are number of pixels.

I'm trying to get a histogram (or a treemap but that would be extra) where each bar takes on the RGB color it represents.

How would I do that?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the color option in pl.bar. Colors need to be normalized to 0-1.

```
colors = {(97, 103, 105): 638059, (129, 140, 143): 562526, (55, 58, 62): 431610, (189, 193, 193): 460605}
normalizedcolors = [[i/256 for i in j] for j in colors.keys()]

import pylab as pl
import numpy as np
dict_index = np.arange(len(colors))
pl.bar(dict_index, colors.values(), align='center', width=0.5, color = normalizedcolors)
pl.xticks(dict_index, colors.keys())
ymax = max(colors.values()) + 1
pl.ylim(0, ymax)
pl.show()
```